# How to get a column average according to date column's last 3 months by grouped columns in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, average

I have these 3 tables:

Table1

| counter_ID | house_ID |
| --- | --- |
| 123456 | 567890 |
| 123457 | 567810 |
| 123463 | 567811 |
| 123478 | 567812 |

Table2

| counter_ID | owner_ID | receipt_ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123456 | **0901987** | 678954 |
| 123457 | **0901987** | 423567 |
| 123463 | **0901987** | 543211 |
| 123478 | **0901987** | 345332 |

Table3

| amount | owner_ID | receipt_ID | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 575 | **0901987** | 678954 | 2020-02-20 |
| 300 | **0901987** | 678954 | 2020-04-21 |
| 450 | **0901987** | 678954 | 2020-05-22 |
| 125 | **0901987** | 678954 | 2020-06-21 |
| 180 | **0901987** | 423567 | 2020-02-20 |
| 350 | **0901987** | 423567 | 2020-03-21 |
| 1200 | **0901987** | 543211 | 2020-02-20 |
| 600 | **0901987** | 543211 | 2020-03-20 |
| 700 | **0901987** | 543211 | 2020-04-20 |
| 380 | **0901987** | 345332 | 2020-02-20 |
| 475 | **0901987** | 345332 | 2020-04-20 |
| 950 | **0901987** | 345332 | 2020-07-20 |
| 110 | **0901987** | 345332 | 2020-08-20 |

The output I want to create:

| owner_ID | counter_ID | receipt_ID | house_ID | avg_Amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0901987 | 123456 | 678954 | 567890 | 362 |
| 0901987 | 123457 | 423567 | 567810 | 265 |
| 0901987 | 123463 | 543211 | 567811 | 833 |
| 0901987 | 123478 | 345332 | 567812 | 478 |

How to create this output from Table1, Table2, Table3?

I want to calculate according to the following formula in the result, column avg_Amount:

Average invoice amount for the last 3 months, but if the invoice days of the same owner_ID and receipt_ID are less than 3 (count(records) in Table3, take the average of that available days.

Comment: Have you made any attempts..? What were they? Why didn't they work? You talk about the `receipt_ID ` being less than `3`, but none of the values for `receipt_ID ` are `< 3`.

Comment: in table3, there is records that count(receipt_ID) < 3. I will edit the question.

Comment: `take the average of that available days.` what does that mean, if it's just the average, how is it different from if there are more than 3 rows

Comment: @Charlieface Average of last 3 months is required. In other words, if there are 4 months of records, the average of the first 3 months is requested. But if there is less than 3 months of registration, the arithmetic average will be taken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely clear what you mean by only wanting 3 months.

It seems perhaps you want to take the average of all rows which are within three months of the earliest row (when partitioning by `receipt_ID`).

For this we can use a window function

```sql
SELECT
  t2.owner_ID,
  t2.counter_ID,
  t2.receipt_ID,
  t1.house_ID,
  avg_Amount = AVG(t3.amount)
FROM Table1 t1
JOIN Table2 t2 ON t2.counter_ID = t1.counter_ID
JOIN (
    SELECT *,
        MaxDate = MAX(t3.[Date]) OVER (PARTITION BY t3.receipt_ID)
    FROM Table3 t3
) t3 ON t3.receipt_ID = t2.receipt_ID
    AND t3.[Date] > DATEADD(month, -12, t3.MaxDate)
GROUP BY
  t2.owner_ID,
  t2.counter_ID,
  t2.receipt_ID,
  t1.house_ID;
```

Comment: Hi Charlieface, Thanks for your reply. Sorry about the delay. Covid-19 vaccine affected me very badly. So I couldn't answer to you before. I want to take the average of amount acording to last 12 months data which is grouped by t2.owner_ID,   t2.counter_ID,  t2.receipt_ID, t1.house_ID. If grouped data include less than 12 months records, I want to get all record's average. However; if it has more than 12 months records, I want to get just only last 12 months record's average.

Comment: What does "last 12 months data" mean: the last 12 months going back from today? Or the latest 12 months available for that group of `owner_ID, counter_ID, receipt_ID, house_ID`?

Comment: It is "the latest 12 months available for that group of owner_ID, counter_ID, receipt_ID, house_ID". In my example table, I wanted to describe it for 3 months.

Comment: Ah so you need the `MAX` date, not the `MIN`. Have fixed